# How to listen for uppercase characters in a JTextPane as the user types

Tags: java, listener, text-editor, jtextpane, uppercase

First time asker.

I have developed a text editor using java's JTextPane. The editor currently does everything an editor should do; open, close, save, saveAs, cut, copy and paste etc. I have a couple of extra buttons that do various things to selected text.

Now my question:
I want one of these methods to be performed every time the user types a word beginning with a capitol letter. I'm just a bit lost as to where to begin with checking if each character is a capitol as the user types.

Hope I've provided enough information.

Thanks

Comment: You wish to check when the user has finished typing a word, e.g. by typing space, ., ? ! etc...

Comment: That could work yeah. if(user types a space) check if the first letter of the previous word is upper case. Or to check on every character if it's an upper case and save the word to a string for manipulation when the space bar is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do when the user types "I"? You don't know what the next character will be. It could be an upper case character, a lower case character or a space.

I'm not sure what type of processing you intend to do every time an upper case character is typed because usually you don't know the context of that character until other characters have been entered.

In any case you intercept changes to the `Document` of the `JTextPane` before the change is made by using a `DocumentFilter`. So you can use the `DocumentFilter` to invoke your method when an upper case character is entered. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.

Also, what happens when the user pastes a String of text to the text pane? Several of the words could contain upper case characters.

Answer (score 0):

As camickr said, DocumentFilter is the best answer, what he needs to do is keep track of `space`, if followed by a capital letter `"[A-Z]"`, then save the `caret` position, when another space is entered the word is finished and the action is fired. BTW, he needs to keep track of not only space, but also new line and tab characters.